# Using Spring Security ACL, how to secure a method that is passed a "String" key?

Tags: spring-security

I understand how to apply Spring security annotations to methods that are passed the domain objects. For example, the following works:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#node, 'write')")
void update(Node node);
```

How ever, I have another method shown below that I am trying to secure:

```
void delete(String nodeName)
```

Since domain object is not available to this method, I am not sure how to use "hasPermission" with this one. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am open to customizing the ACL implementation though in this particular case, any such customization should work with not just "Node" object but all other domain objects as well.

Thanks,

Raghu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you're deleting by name as opposed to by identity. The way you do that is you look up the object you wish to delete and then, once you have it, pass it to a *real* deletion method that follows the pattern of the first operation in your question. The check whether the object can be deleted by the user is done *after* lookup. You get a pattern a bit like this:

```java
void delete(String name) {
    Node node = nodeFinder.lookup(name);
    if (node == null)
        throw new NoSuchNodeException(name);
    underlyingEngine.delete(node);
}
```

The `nodeFinder` and (especially) `underlyingEngine` should be injected beans so that Spring can wrap them with the required security checks. (The `nodeFinder` checks should be whether the user is allowed to know about the named node at all, the `underlyingEngine` should focus on whether the particular operation — deletion in this case — is permitted.)

Note that you can also apply the `@PreAuthorize` directly to the `Node` (provided you decide to make them into beans) through the use of [`#this` in the expression](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html#d0e12007).

Comment: This answer makes sense even though the "underlyingEngine" in our case is the DAO itself which provides the interface "deleteByName()". It thus exhibits exact same problem as described here.

Comment: The `nodeFinder` and the `underlyingEngine` might actually be the same bean; they're really rôles and not actual objects.